# REST API issue in PowerBI to GoogleBigQuery

Tags: rest, google-bigquery, powerbi

This has been an issue every now and then for the last year but now since last Friday it's dramatic.

None of our queries are refreshing like they were before.

Message:

> Error interacting with REST API: Couldn't connect to server ERROR
>   [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverOAuthSupport] (8701) Error interacting with
>   REST API: Couldn't connect to server Table:

Notes:

- PowerBI - Desktop refresh works
- The table or view triggering the error differs, it's not always the same table or view.
- It seems to be related to running parallel queries, loading from the same table simultaneously.
- Dataflow jobs are reported to be working, since the load sequentially

Can Microsoft and Google talk to each other? On both sides they are pointing to each other.

Comment: Is this on service or desktop? Have you updated your PowerBI desktop to the latest?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this has affected several users in the last days.

I found this [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/145895341) where it's said that the BigQuery Eng team is working on this. I could also see that there are no workarounds available for now.

Feel free to ask for updates or add additional questions on it.